# jQuery hover images carousel timeout overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm building a webpage which shows products. When hovering over the product image, a slideshow-like event should start. You'll see photo's of the product in several states.
I've coded this with jQuery and I'm facing a kinda annoying bug.

When you hover over several products very fast and then leave your mouse on one product, it will slide through the images very fast.

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="productContainer" data-product-id="1">
    <img src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/inside/bmw-inside.jpg" class="mainProductImage" />
    <div class="hoverImages">
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/inside/bmw-inside-1.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/inside/bmw-inside-2.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/inside/bmw-inside-3.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/inside/bmw-inside-4.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/inside/bmw-inside-5.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productContainer" data-product-id="1">
    <img src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/outside/bmw-outside.jpg" class="mainProductImage" />
    <div class="hoverImages">
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/outside/bmw-outside-1.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/outside/bmw-outside-2.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/outside/bmw-outside-3.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/outside/bmw-outside-4.jpg" />
      <img src="" data-lazy-src="http://detestdivisie.nl/upload/images/hover-tests/outside/bmw-outside-5.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The Javscript class that is responsible for handling the events looks like this:

```
CategoryProductImages = function () {
  this.className = 'CategoryProductImages';
  this.version   = '0.1.0';

  this.mouseOver         = false;
  this.currentElement    = null;
  this.currentCategoryId = 0;
  this.currentImageList  = [];        
  this.currentImageKey   = 0;

  /**
   * CategoryProductImages.init()
   *
   * Initializes the class that is reponsible for handling the
   * mouse over and outs for the products.
   *
   * This method will call the createObserver method.
   */
  this.init = function () {
    console.log('Called ' + this.className + '.init()');

    this.createObservers();
  };

  /**
   * CategoryProductImages.createObservers()
   *
   * Will handle the mouse over and out events.
   */         
  this.createObservers = function () {
    console.log('Called ' + this.className + '.createObservers()');

    var thisObj = this;

    jQuery('.productContainer').hover(
      /** Called when mouse of the user moves over the element. **/
      function () {
        console.log('Mouse over .productContainer');

        thisObj.mouseOver         = true;                    
        thisObj.currentElement    = jQuery(this);   
        thisObj.currentCategoryId = thisObj.currentElement.data('category-id');                 

        console.log('Lets\'s work for category id ' + thisObj.currentCategoryId);

        thisObj.currentElement.find('.hoverImages img').each(function() {
          thisObj.currentImageList.push(jQuery(this).data('lazy-src'));
        });

        thisObj.iterate();          
      },
      /** Called immediatly after the mouse of the user leaves the element **/
      function () {
        console.log('Mouse out .productContainer');

        thisObj.currentElement   = null;
        thisObj.mouseOver        = false;                    
        thisObj.currentImageList = new Array();
        thisObj.currentImageKey  = 0
      }
    );
  };

  this.iterate = function () {
    console.log('Called ' + this.className + '.iterate()');

    if (this.mouseOver && this.currentImageList.length > 0) {
      console.log('Will now start the iteration process');

      this.currentElement.find('img.mainProductImage').prop('src', this.currentImageList[0]);

      thisObj = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('First image shown, will now show next image.');

        thisObj.nextImage(thisObj.currentCategoryId);
      }, 3000)
    } else {
      console.log('Won\'t iterate, because the mouse of the user has left the element, of there are no images to show.');
    }    
  };

  this.nextImage = function (currentCategoryId) {
    console.log('Called ' + this.className + '.nextImage()');

    if (this.mouseOver && this.currentImageList.length > 0 && currentCategoryId == this.currentCategoryId) {
      console.log('MouseOver still active, and images are found, show next image.');

      this.currentImageKey += 1;

      if (typeof this.currentImageList[this.currentImageKey] == 'undefined') {
        console.log('OH NO! We\'ve reached the end of the list. Letst start all over again.');

        this.currentImageKey = 0;
      }

      this.currentElement.find('img.mainProductImage').prop('src', this.currentImageList[this.currentImageKey]);

      thisObj = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Okay, we\'ve waited for three seconds, NEXT! :)');

        thisObj.nextImage(currentCategoryId)
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      console.log('Iteration for ' + currentCategoryId + ' stopped');
      console.log('Mouse over: ');
      console.log(this.mouseOver);
      console.log('Image list length: ');
      console.log(this.currentImageList.length);
      console.log('nextImage category id: ');
      console.log(currentCategoryId);
      console.log('Current category id:');
      console.log(this.currentCategoryId);
      console.log('#########################');
    }
  }
};

var categoryProductImagesObject = new CategoryProductImages();
categoryProductImagesObject.init();
```

The make it all more clear I've created a CodePen example. Please mouse over product 1 and product 2 very fast and then leave your mouse on product 1. You'll see it will loop through the product images way to fast.

**http://codepen.io/wdivo/pen/lamsq**

The time it should take before and image is replaced by another one is 3 seconds.
I am overlooking something, because obviously several setTimeouts are working near eachother, while there should only be 1 active setTimeout.

What should I do to make sure only 1 "active" setTimeout is running?

Simply said, I'd want to stop all the previous setTimeouts if a new one gets activated.

I'm now looking into clearInterval, but can't think of a way to implement it...